# Using jQuery the youtube url has to place in the text box url content is to load in the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-youtube-api

While i have trying that the youtube URL is placed in the text box the URL content is to be displayed in the iframe. But the embed link is not opening. Is their any any extra functionality is needed to open the youtube video.

```
$("input#url").on("keyup",function(){
    var url=this.value;
     $("iframe").attr("src",url);
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#url").on("blur", function () {
        var url = $("#url").val();
        $("iframe").attr("src", url);
    });
});
```

Try this on blur event i.e when focus is lost then event is triggered